Quote Line Group Field in Order Object always coming as null before or after insert Triggers
I want to display the values of the Subscription Vendor Name and Delivery Mode fields in the Order object.
The logic is as follows: When the order is created, it should check the Quote Line Group (referred to as quoteLineGroupName in the code) and also check the Quote level. Within the quote lines, we have the Subscription Vendor Name and Delivery Mode. These values should be displayed in the Order object, but only when the Quote Line lookup's Quote Line Group matches the Order lookup's Quote Line Group.
However, when I attempt this approach, the Order fields are coming through, but the Quote Line Group Name is always appearing as null.
What could be the issue?
public with sharing class OrderTriggerHelper {
    public static Map<Id,SBQQ__Quote__c> quoteMap;
    public static Map<Id, List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c>> quoteLineGroupMap = new Map<Id, List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c>>();
public static void afterInsert(List<SObject> newItems ) {
        List<Order> orderList = (List<Order>)newItems; 
        
       Set<Id> quoteIdSet = new Set<Id>();
      
      for (Order ord : orderList) {
            quoteIdSet.add(ord.SBQQ__Quote__c);
        }

        if (!quoteIdSet.isEmpty()) {
            // Query for Quote Lines and group by Quote Line Group
            Map<Id, List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c>> quoteLineGroupMap = new Map<Id, List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c>>();
            String quoteLineQueryString = 'SELECT SBQQ__Quote__c, Subscription_Vendor_Name__c, Delivery_Mode__c, SBQQ__Group__c FROM SBQQ__QuoteLine__c WHERE SBQQ__Quote__c IN :quoteIdSet';
            for (SBQQ__QuoteLine__c ql : Database.query(quoteLineQueryString)) {
                if (ql.SBQQ__Group__c != null) {
                    if (!quoteLineGroupMap.containsKey(ql.SBQQ__Group__c)) {
                        quoteLineGroupMap.put(ql.SBQQ__Group__c, new List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c>());

                    quoteLineGroupMap.get(ql.SBQQ__Group__c).add(ql);
                }
            }
          }
        }

            // Process the orders with data from Quote Lines
            for (Order ord : orderList) {
                Id quoteLineGroupId = ord.Quote_Line_Group_Name__r.ID;
           

                // Check if Quote Line Group exists in the map and is not null
                if (quoteLineGroupId != null && quoteLineGroupMap.containsKey(quoteLineGroupId)) {
                    List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> quoteLines = quoteLineGroupMap.get(quoteLineGroupId);

                    // Perform the comparison logic on Quote Lines within the same Quote Line Group
                    for (SBQQ__QuoteLine__c ql : quoteLines) {
                        // Here you can add your specific comparison logic
                        ord.Subscription_Vendor_Name__c = ql.Subscription_Vendor_Name__c;
                        ord.Delivery_Mode__c = ql.Delivery_Mode__c;
                    }
                }
            }
       }
}


Not relevant to the issue at hand, but you should seriously consider using a "static" query ([SELECT Id ... FROM ...]) instead of a "dynamic" one (i.e. building a string and calling database.query()).

Also, it's not clear what your problem is. A more accurate and precise description of the issue would be helpful. If you're getting an error, [edit] your question to include the error (verbatim) and separately point out the code that the line number points to (because you haven't given us the full class, we wouldn't know what line #x would be). If some code isn't executing that you think should be, tell us what that code is.

As written, this code has at least 2 fatal flaws. 1: I should think that this code would not compile/save because Id quoteLineGroupId is defined/declared inside of a loop, and you're trying to access it outside of the loop (i.e. that variable isn't in scope where you try to use it). 2: You're only ever adding quote lines to your map when you're first adding the group id to the map.

Hi @DerekF Thank you for addressing the issue and updating the code
